# How to close all proceses without restarting a machine?

Tags: process, kill

I have a lot of processes running and I need to kill them all.

[image]

How can I do this without restarting a machine?

Comment: What do you think will be left of your computer system if you kill all your processes?  What is your desired end state?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just use:

`disown -r`

It will kill all processes and you don't need to restart your machine.

Comment: This assumes that every running process on the machine is child of the current interactive shell. I consider that unlikely.

Comment: @mikeserv: I imagine OP means "jobs" rather than processes.  Otherwise, this question doesn't make an ounce of sense.

Comment: That does not kill processes; it simply removes them from the shell's job management so they continue to run in the background and will *not* be killed if you exit the shell.

Comment: @Kevin - process -> job is a pretty big leap. I likento take people at their word.

Comment: @mikeserv: If it wasn't what they wanted, they wouldn't have accepted.

Comment: @Kevin - duh. That was dumb of me then, huh? In that case we need to downvote this question, I guess. You know - the question had 7 upvotes last night - now only two and only 1 downvote. The answer w/ 2 upvotes used to have at least 4. A lot of people changed their minds about this, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Whatever you do, there has to be ***at least one*** process running. Or rather, when you *can* do this, you will cause the kernel to dump core and panic. An immediate reboot will probably follow - or else nothing will happen at all until you power cycle your machine.

There is kernel space and there is user space. The user space is propped up from boot by PID 1 - `init`. To kill *all* of the processes is to kill user space and then what would you do with the computer anyway?

When the system is booted the system's firmware or some intermediate boot-loader executes the kernel in memory. The kernel does some sanity checks and looks for `init`. If it finds it, and `init` does anything useful, eventually you will be able to use your computer. If it does not then you will not be able to use your computer.

For the rest of the life of that boot cycle the kernel services user space - which is to say, `init`'s children. Take those away and it has no purpose. And it probably *won't* be happy about it, either.

Answer (score 2):

More seriously, rather than the radical *kill*'ing, you can switch to maintenance mode (aka *Single User*):

```
# as root:
/sbin/init 1
```

Your system will switch to *runlevel 1*, dedicated to maintenance tasks. [Nearly] All processes will be [nicely] killed, all file systems unmounted and interactive login directed to the console (the `console` boot argument).

To later go back to the multi-user runlevel:

```
/sbin/init 3
```

or, to enable the graphical login manager:

```
/sbin/init 5
```

Comment: Runlevel 2 is multi-user and includes the gui... all higher runlevels are the same, at least on debian based distros.  I believe on some other distros, 2 does not include the gui, but 3-5 are still all the same.

Comment: @psusi These runlevels are from my Gentoo machine `man runlevel` in fact. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: @terdon Have you got no sense of humour, then? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the [magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) is enabled on your system, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Scrn/SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or execute

```
echo e > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

to send SIGTERM to all processes except init (PID 1).

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Scrn/SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or

```
echo i > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

to send SIGKILL instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill all processes by following command:

```
kill -9 -1
```

From [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/kill.1.html):-

```
$ man kill | sed -n '5,6p' ; man kill | awk 'NR>=38 && NR<=40'
NAME
       kill - send a signal to a process
EXAMPLES
       kill -9 -1
              Kill all processes you can kill.
```

This will kill all processes and you will be redirected to login screen.

Comment: i think you may have overlooked a very important detail in the documentation you reference there.

Comment: @mikeserv ok; I've revised post

Answer (score 0):

If your distro uses `systemd`, you can switch to minimal `systemd` target:

```
systemctl isolate emergency.target
```

This will kill almost all applications, move your system to single-user root login mode. After this you execute:

```
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

You will be brought back to X. This will accompish almost a reboot.